# Symbol list could not be resolved

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, symbols

I have a strange error that appear in the folowing code:

```
#ifndef BALL_H_
#define BALL_H_

#include <list>

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

using namespace sf;

class Ball : public CircleShape {

protected:
    unsigned int mass;  //the mass of the ball
    float xSpeed;       //the x component of the ball's speed
    float ySpeed;       //the y component of the ball's speed

public:
    //Constructor : need the screen dimensions to center it
    Ball(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height);

    //function that update the position of the ball and handle collisions.
    void update(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, list<Ball>::iterator *it);
};
#endif /* BALL_H_ */
```

The error is : Symbol 'list' could not be resolved. However, I am using the list library in another file in the same project and it works perfectly.

I am using eclipse and linux.

The only solution I found so far in the eclipse forum was to close and reopen the project... didn't work for me.

Thanks for any help =)

Comment: You need `std::list`, you forgot to specify the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `std::` in front of `list<...>`. I assume wherever else you are using it you have `using namespace std` or something equivalent at the top of the file.

`void update(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, std::list<Ball>::iterator *it);`

Comment: Ahaha yes I forgot the namespace, my bad!

Thanks!